# How to use Mixins for every type of inheritance?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, design-patterns, mixins

I've recently saw the concept of Mixin in javascript mainly through [the article Real Mixins with javascript classes](http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/). And as I understand is a way to do multiple inheritance with abstract classes and it is more like a composition than an inheritance. I'm also reading about the concept composition over inheritance, as in [the article Composition Over Inheritance](https://medium.com/humans-create-software/composition-over-inheritance-cb6f88070205). I'm aware that the discussion about inheritance and composition can be very long, but I've chosen to avoid inheritance as much as I can (at least for now).

So I would like to use Mixins as much as I can with ES6 and in most of examples I see three classes in action like `class A extends MixinB(C)`. What if I want to extend only the class B? Would I do something like `class A extends MixinB(Object)`? This might be an anti pattern as the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes) states.

Note that I could do a direct inheritance like `class A extends B`, but like this `B` is not a Mixin anymore and I would need a different declaration of `B` if I would like to use it as a Mixin.

Comment: “Inheritance is not always the right pattern” does not mean “shoehorn this new thing you learned into every place you previously used inheritance”.

Comment: Beware there are JavaScript bloggers who get composition entirely wrong. https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/5dxq6i/composition_over_inheritance/da8bplv/ . Mixins and multiple inheritance are indeed the same thing, but neither are composition.

Comment: > This might be an anti pattern as the Mozilla documentation states. |
The MDN documentation is talking about monkey patching, which is indeed bad, but monkey patching isn't what `class extends` does.

Comment: @JeffM ... with your reddit link user *MoTTs_* there does refer to `aggregation`. So when the comment states *Composition is containment, inheritance is mixing*, it should be corrected to *containment is aggregation and "mixing in" can be achieved by both composition and inheritance*. When people use kind of *Mixin/Trait* patterns, `Object.assign` or `class ... extends` they, at least in *JavaScript*, always compose; but inheritance in addition provides/covers subtyping. The OP's Q then will change to *"How to use Mixins for every type of composition?"*

Comment: @PeterSeliger Composition and aggregation are virtually the same thing. They differ only in ownership of the contained object. And however we choose to distinguish between mixin or trait or inheritance doesn't change the concrete problems we encounter. `Object.assign`, for example, is still susceptible to the fragile base problem, an issue that we normally associate with inheritance.

Comment: I see an overuse of Inheritance and it's not a good thing to do, so shouldn't "multiple inheritance"/compositon done by Mixin be a better pattern to overuse? TL;DR The @JeffM reddit link is good because I actually thought that the video had all the concepts right, so I'll need to revisit some concepts. But my basic point is that I've been writing code without thinking that much in the architecture and I saw myself not being able to grow functionalities as easy as it should be. So my main goal is to write code that fits mainly in the Open/Closed principle (as well as other SOLID principles).

Answer (score 0):

I think that a solution for what you are looking for it would be to change the definition of `Mixin` functions.

Instead of having:

```
MixinB(WhateverClass)
```

You could have:

```
Mixin(MainClass, otherClass1, otherClass2...)
```

Where this would be true:

```
MixinB(C) = Mixin(B, C)
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't like the sound of this!

> So I would like to use Mixins as much as I can

Use mixins where appropriate, not because you want to use them. Inheritance is appropriate for fixed, strong relationships. Mixins are useful when you have a small piece of functionality you want to share with a number of classes that are not related otherwise.

Comment: Please, don't think I'm trying to make my code worse with Mixins, what I'm saying is that "I would like to use Mixins as much as I can" and by the word "can" I mean "so here is better to use an inheritance? Using a Mixin would be hacky an inapropriated? Ok, I'll use inheritance".

Your answer is more like a comment as you are not answering the question that I did.